# Android studio on Ubuntu will not open

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

Not sure what happened. I was using it and then switched to editing an api file in Geany, then went back to Android Studio and got this error below. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but still no go. Any ideas?

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

-----
JRE 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
/snap/android-studio/94/android-studio/jre/jre"
```

Answer (score 18):

Remove `lib` folder `.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/marketplace`

or execute command

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/marketplace/lib
```

It's working for me :-)

Comment: Why is that happening?

Comment: @Mosius It's happens because of Markdown lib .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in ubantu:  go to -> HOME/.LOCAL/SHARE/GOOGLE/ANDROIDSUTDIO4.1/marketplace
marketplace file need to remove then start android studio working fine